# Can I add style class on sap.m.objectnumber?

Tags: css, sapui5

I have a decimal number so I am displaying this with the objectnumber element. But the number is in bold and I don't want that. Can I add a css class to this element? If not how can I solve this?

This is the element:

```
<ObjectNumber
    number="{
        path: 'PriceIBTW',
        formatter: '.formatter.moneyFormatter'
    }"
    unit="{Valuta}"/>
```

I have tried looking for a style or class attribute but they don't seem to have either one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **nistv4n** said before, `emphasized` property is availablein ObjectNuber. This solve the bold styling.

Then if you want to add custom CSS you can set the `class` property as explained in the [API documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw751abap/helpdata/en/72/3f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796/content.htm).

Here a functional snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <title></title>
  
  <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
   id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
   data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" 
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'
   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
  </script>


  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
   <mvc:View controllerName="my.own.Controller" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Panel>
                <HBox>
                  <Label text="Standard ObjectNumber: " />
                  <ObjectNumber number="25" unit="EUR" />
                </HBox>
                <HBox>
                  <Label text="ObjectNumber without emphasized number: " />
                  <ObjectNumber number="25" unit="EUR" emphasized="false" />
                </HBox>
                <HBox>
                  <Label text="ObjectNumber with CSS class: " />
                  <ObjectNumber number="25" unit="EUR" class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin"/>
                </HBox>
         </Panel>
   </mvc:View>
  </script>
  <script>
   var myView;
   
   var myController = new sap.ui.controller("my.own.Controller", {
    
   })

   myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()});
          
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');
   
  </script>
  
 </head>
 <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that without custom CSS. `ObjectNumber` has a dedicated property for that called `emphasized`. Set it to `false` (by default it's set to `true`).

Relevant API document: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ObjectNumber.html